# What to expect when running a chkdsk on C:?

Tags: windows-10, asus-laptop, chkdsk

Please excuse me if this sounds stupid. This is the first time I have attempted disk checking.

Am working on Asus A555L running Windows 10. After a forced shut down, my cursor started jumping accompanied by error sounds once every second. To troubleshoot, I started with disk checking the C: drive.

```
chkdsk C: /r
```

(Before check disk, I had tried booting Windows in Safe mode but my laptop wasn't able to. After the restart it just got stuck on a black screen. I used the power button to switch it off and then on again, then ran the check disk from command promt)

After the command, on restarting the laptop, it is stuck on a black screen since the past 2 hours even though it's switched on.

My questions are- Is this normal behavior for C drive disk checking?

Does it boot to a black screen and stay there till chkdsk is complete?

If yes, on average how long does it last? And if not, is there anything I can do now to intervene?

Comment: chkdisk is a utility, it performs various functions, and status of each stage is provided.  It sounds like your disk has failed.  Hopefully you have a recent backup of your personal data.

Comment: No to the first 2 questions. Q3, depends on how large the hard drive is, Q4 yes, do a hard shut down since chkdsk is not running since there is no text output just a black screen.

Comment: If you have access to another computer, remove the problem drive and connect it to the other computer, either as a secondary internal drive or using an external enclosure or USB interface.  Boot the other computer from its own drive or connect after that computer is booted.  See if the drive is recognized and try to run chkdsk on it there.